# how to insert new line in bash shell for variable?

Tags: bash

I have two variables var1 and var2. The contents of each variables come from bash shell grep command.

`echo $var1` prints
`123 465 326 8080`

`echo $var2` prints
`sila kiran hinal juku`

Now I want to print the above into following formats in Linux bash shell

```
123 sila
465 kiran
326 hinal
8080 juku
```

So how can I print this way in bash shell??

Comment: Could you indent the output parts with 4 spaces? I think you have multiline strings, while everything now is displayed on one line. The 4 spaces indentation put it in code formatting

Comment: probably using the `join` command, except I'd need to see how $var1 and $var2 got created.

Answer (score 2):

What about?

```
$ paste -d" " <(echo $var1 | xargs -n1) <(echo $var2 | xargs -n1)
```

We can even skip the *echo*:

```
$ paste -d" " <(xargs -n1 <<< $var1) <(xargs -n1 <<< $var2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Without a loop:

```
$ var1="123 465 326 8080"
$ var2="sila kiran hinal juku"
$ var1=($var1); var2=($var2)
$ saveIFS=IFS
$ IFS=$'\n'
$ paste <(echo "${a[*]}") <(echo "${b[*]}"
$ IFS=$saveIFS
```

With a loop (assumes that the two strings have the same number of words):

```
$ var1="123 465 326 8080"
$ var2="sila kiran hinal juku"
$ var2=($var2)
$ for s in $var1; do echo $s ${vars[i++]}; done
```

Answer (score 1):

Using file descriptors and a while-loop:

```
var1="123 465 326 8080"
var2="sila kiran hinal juku"

IFS=" " exec 7< <(printf "%s\n" $var1) 8< <(printf "%s\n" $var2)

while read -u7 f1 && read -u8 f2; do
   echo "$f1 $f2"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd store them into arrays `$var1[]` and `$var2[]` instead of a some long string and then iterate through the arrays with a loop to output it the way you want.

If you don't want ot use arrays, you could use awk and the iterator from a loop to print out the names one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

```
join <(echo $var1 | sed -r  's/ +/\n/g' | cat -n) <(echo $var2 | sed -r  's/ +/\n/g' | cat -n) -o "1.2,2.2"
```